# attribute disabled not function with Xhtml

Tags: javascript, css, html, xhtml, attributes

I have a page Xhtml where I have a span inside a td.

When I put the attribute disabled = "disabled" I expect that the cell becomes gray and
in fact, on ie9 is so. Unfortunately on chrome, firefox and IE10 is not so.

The cursor is disabled, but the cell does not turn gray.
Can you tell me why.

Thanks.

My code:

```
<tr>
<td background="background.gif" disabled="disabled" id="btnIdentify">
    <span type="text">Identify</span>
</td>
```

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't work in all the major browsers as disabled is not a valid attribute for the td tag!
You have to find another solution to achieve what you want.